# How to open an Excel Template file from different users on different PCs from the same Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I've setup a basic macro to open a template file from the default templates folder from an open excel file, which of course works perfectly fine on the PC it was created on, but I need to run the same file from another user on the same network.

The file I'm attempting to run the macro from is stored on a NAS device so it's accessible from my PC and my laptop. As the laptop has a different username the macro doesn't work. If I change the file path of the file in the macro to run from the templates folder on the laptop to that specific user, then of course it won't work when I run it from the PC.

The macro:

```
Workbooks.Add Template:= _
  "C:\Users\[user1]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\[filename].xltx"
```

**Is it possible to run a macro to open a template file from the default template folder, as above, from one excel file (let's call it "test.xltx") from different user accounts, i.e. user1 and user2 without having to change the user name in the file path every time?**

If so, what would the code be I could use?

I should point out that I don't need to run the "test.xltx" at the same time from different user accounts. I'm the only one accessing the file, but I do need to run it from my PC or laptop, hence the different user accounts.

Comment: I'm not sure I catch your point. We usually use sharepoint files if everyone needs to access the same files. If you want to grab the id, then feel free to feel ashamed, took me a minute of googling to find it.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting comment, I've never used Sharepoint so I don't know anything about it. Thank s for your input, but it doesn't really help :P

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
  Filename = "ertdfgcvb"
  InputBox " ", , "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & _
    "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates" & Filename & ".xltx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Any chance you could add an explanation and name the function something useful?

Comment: It's an XY Problem I think, `Application.AutoRecover.Path` is what OP is looking for. `...\Roaming\...` is the default folder for that.

Comment: Thanks for your input, In comparison to users on here I'm a complete noob when it comes to macro code. I tried the input box code above, adding in the correct filename and ran it. It worked fine in as far as the input box appearing with the path and the filename, but clicking on 'OK' did nothing. How then do I actually open the template file?

Is there a way to run this without opening the input box?

Comment: The inputbox was to show you a copy-able path, you'll need to use it instead of the path string you have in your post. E.g. `Workbooks.Add Template:= "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & _
    "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates" & Filename & ".xltx"`

Comment: Well, user3819867, that worked a treat :) I had to make a slight little adjustment so it would work;

Workbooks.Add Template:= "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\" & Filename & ".xltx"

Removed the underscore to keep the code on one line, removed the space after the underscore, and added a backslash after 'Templates' (and of course, for those who may be reading this after finding it in a search, add the filename before '.xltx' :))

Thank you very much for your help, it has been hugely appreciated. 

Cheers :)